# ngx chart resizing issue

Tags: angular5, ngx-charts

Original screen, [image][image]

Hi I am able to stretch the chart and increase the width but as soon as I hit button to shrink the width to original state; the chart is not resized .Its still using the expanded dimension

Above are screenshots of overlapping charts.
Anyone please help.